# How to integrate Piwik analytics with Ionic2 application?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-routing, matomo

Does anyone know how to integrate Piwik analytics with Ionic 2 application ?

In Ionic 2 native documentation, they have provided a plugin named Google analytics which connects to Google's native Universal Analytics SDK.

I am searching for any plugins / git examples / documentation which provide me some deep knowledge about how Piwik analytics can be integrated with Ionic 2 application.
Please guide me for the integrate piwik analytic and track the page,clicks etc.
Please try to help me is that possible to create sample application like google analytic.

Comment: same as problem, please any one let me know how to integrate matomo piwik tracking system in ionic 3 app

Comment: If you have used Matomo to track your cordova ionic mobile app please leave a comment here: https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo/issues/14375